# How to optimize / normalize flat sql table

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchical-data

I got this flat table, and I am trying to figure out if it is in first 3 normal forms, and if I can optimize it somehow for easier use.

```
parent_id | child_id  
        1 | 1    
        1 | 2  
        1 | 3  
        2 | 4  
        3 | 7  
        3 | 9  
        9 | 10
```

So what is my concern here... I have these values repeating, and basically nested hierarchical structure. When I execute a query on this table, 
I need to group up the data in my application code. Is there anyway, 
to organize this data so that I can get it for tree display purposes, 
just by executing SQL query? And is there anything wrong with this table considering normalization?

This is the desired output (see image below, it is an example). I am using MySQL.

**Tree Structure**

[image]

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have updated my question, thank you.

Comment: Hierarchical does not mean that it isn't normalized, or that it needs to be normalized. Normalization generally applied to some value with multiple columns that is repeated (like gender, company division, etc.) and could be coded in a smaller table. This doesn't need to be normalized.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

3rd normal form has always been sufficient for my data needs, and is so ubiquitous that when we say "normalized data" we assume we mean 3rd normal form. The only time I've see non-normalized data on purpose was very limited, specific situations.

Your `parent_id`, `child_id` table is keeping your data normalized, effectively. I assume these columns are the primary keys in the respective tables.

First, the above is called a *join table* because that's its purpose: links rows in an n-n relationship, that is 1-many, many-many, etc.

If there was no join table then you'd need a parent table column for every child row linked. Ditto for the child table if needing to query from the child end of the relationship. That is a situation of unnormalized data. And that obviously is impractical.

Then use the join table in a query to get at the related data.

```
select pt.a, ct.b
from parentTable pt
join myJoinTable jt on pt.id = jt.parent_id
join childTable ct on jt.child_id = ct.id
order by jt.parent_id, jt.child_id
```

You probably want to `order by` the primary keys